# Expectation of product of stochastic integral and brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expectation, stochastic-integrals

Find the covariance:

$$
COV((\int_t^T(T-s)dW_s), W_t) 
$$

I used the covariance formula: COV(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(XY) as E(X)=E(Y)=0

But I am stuck on figuring out the expectation of the product:

$$
E(\int_t^T(T-s)W_tdW_s)
$$

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain what is $W_s$ in the first formula, since $s$ is the running time of the stochastic integral?

Comment: sorry, this was meant to be W(t), I've edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite these two factors as
$$\int_t^T(T-s)dW_s=\int_0^Tf(s)dW_s,\qquad W_t=\int_0^Tg(s)dW_s,
$$
for some suitable functions $f$ and $g$, then use the general result that
$$
E\left(\int_0^Tf(s)dW_s\cdot\int_0^Tg(s)dW_s\right)=E\left(\int_0^Tf(s)g(s)ds\right).
$$
The answer should be
$$
0.
$$
Of course, more direct approaches exist, for example the fact that
$$\int_t^T(T-s)dW_s$$
depends only on the process $\overline W$ defined by $\overline W_s=W_{t+s}-W_t$ for every $s\geqslant0$ since it coincides with
$$
\int_0^{T-t}(T-t-s)d\overline W_{s}.
$$
This yields the stronger result that the two factors are in fact independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how did you conclude that:

$$
E[\int_0^Tf(s)g(s)ds]
$$

is zero?

Comment: Well, I followed my own hints, so to speak. Did you try to follow them yourself?

Comment: Well, I'm just trying to figure out what f(s) and g(s) are, what I've got is that:

$$
f(s) = (T-S)I(s>t)
$$

$$
g(s) = I(s<t)
$$

Where I is an indicator. 

But those values of f(s) and g(s) give me 

$$
0.5T^2
$$
for the expectation.

Comment: Nevermind, the product of two indicator functions on non over lapping ranges is zero, that's what was confusing me.
Thanks again

Comment: Indeed. Well done.

Comment: +1 ... Would the downvoters care to comment?